# When to use "ya había" and when to use "habia"?

Tags: gramática

I'm trying to use the past perfect and in my textbook they use *ya había*.

What is that? What does it mean and how is it different from *había*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Había" is the past pefect as in "had". "Ya había" is as remarking that something was done before. Example: I had eaten (yo había comido). I had eaten already (yo ya había comido).